# Error while trying to export DataGridView as pdf

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, itext, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to export a populated datagridview with the following code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports DGVPrinterHelper
Imports iTextSharp
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.IO     

Private Sub Export_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
        MsgBox("Enter Filename to create PDF")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ExportDataToPDFTable()
        MsgBox("PDF Created Successfully")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim dataTable As New Data.DataTable("MyDataTable")
    'Create another DataColumn Name
    For column As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        Dim dataColumn_1 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(column).HeaderText.ToString(), GetType(String))
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn_1)
        'Now Add some row to newly created dataTable
        Dim dataRow As DataRow
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow()
            ' Important you have create New row
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(column).HeaderText.ToString()) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(column).Value.ToString()
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
        Next i
    Next column
    dataTable.AcceptChanges()
    Return dataTable
End Function

Private Sub ExportDataToPDFTable()
    Dim paragraph As New Paragraph
    Dim doc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 10)
    Dim wri As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(SaveFileDialog1.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
    doc.Open()

    Dim font12BoldRed As New iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE Or iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLDITALIC, BaseColor.RED)
    Dim font12Bold As New iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)
    Dim font12Normal As New iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)

    Dim p1 As New Phrase
    p1 = New Phrase(New Chunk("PDF From Datagridview Data", font12BoldRed))
    doc.Add(p1)

    'Create instance of the pdf table and set the number of column in that table
    Dim PdfTable As New PdfPTable(5)
    PdfTable.TotalWidth = 490.0F
    'fix the absolute width of the table
    PdfTable.LockedWidth = True
    'relative col widths in proportions - 1,4,1,1 and 1
    Dim widths As Single() = New Single() {1.0F, 4.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F}
    PdfTable.SetWidths(widths)
    PdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = 1 ' 0 --> Left, 1 --> Center, 2 --> Right
    PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 2.0F

    'pdfCell Decleration
    Dim PdfPCell As PdfPCell = Nothing

    'Assigning values to each cell as phrases
    PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Taxcode", font12Bold)))
    'Alignment of phrase in the pdfcell
    PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER
    'Add pdfcell in pdftable
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell)
    PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Tax Name", font12Bold)))
    PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell)
    PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Cess Tax", font12Bold)))
    PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell)
    PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Sales Tax", font12Bold)))
    PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell)
    PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Other Tax", font12Bold)))
    PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER
    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell)

    Dim dt As DataTable = GetDataTable()
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        'Now add the data from datatable to pdf table
        For rows As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            For column As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(dt.Rows(rows)(column).ToString(), font12Normal))
                If column = 0 Or column = 1 Then
                    PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT
                Else
                    PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT
                End If
                PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell)
            Next
        Next
        'Adding pdftable to the pdfdocument
        doc.Add(PdfTable)
    End If
    doc.Close()
End Sub
```

When I run the program a click the button it prompts me with the SaveFileDialog, but once I click save I get the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable'." at the "Return dataTable" line in the Private Function GetDataTable(). Can anyone help me resolve this issue? And please feel free to point out other errors with my code (if there are any)

Comment: Turn `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` both on, that should help you see your problems a little easier. I don't know why @Jeff's answer was deleted, I'm pretty sure he's correct. You've got two different classes named `DataTable` so you need to full qualify them. You can also often make your life easier by getting rid of the `as` in `Dim dt As DataTable = GetDataTable()` and just change it to `Dim dt = GetDataTable()`

Comment: I can't have those options on because they give me a ton of other errors for my program that work if they're not on. I tried changing what you suggested, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: I won't tell you how to write your code, that's your choice, but I can tell you those errors and warnings exist for a very good reason. There's a cast or something else implicit that the compiler is trying to tell you might cause problems down the road. The compiler is going to make a guess for you and it might be correct but it would just like you to confirm its choice. But I won't hound you on it. Anyways, did you change both? `Private Function GetDataTable() As System.Data.DataTable` and `Dim dt = GetDataTable()`

Comment: I didn't change both until just now when you told me to and now it outputs just fine. Thank you! Now I have to actually edit the writing process to cater to my datagridview column and row headers since this layout was a pure template. Thanks again!